# Google Chrome @keyframes and filters

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have a problem with the `@keyframes` using Google Chrome.
I'm using the `greyscale filter` and I want to disable it please to `@keyframes`

The code is working well using Mozilla Firefox, but not working with Google Chrome. Instead of starting at `greyscale(40%)` it looks like it is starting at `greyscale(100%)`.

Here is my CSS :

```
.contact-icon{
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 120px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(40%);
    filter: grayscale(40%);
}

.contact-icon:hover{
    animation-name: selected-icon;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}

@keyframes selected-icon{
    0% {-webkit-filter: grayscale(40%); filter: grayscale(40%); max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px;}
    100% {-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); filter: grayscale(0%); max-width: 140px; max-height: 140px;}
}
```

I also tried using `@-webkit-keyframes` but it is giving exactly the same result.
I did a little gif of what I have atm usign Google Chrome: 
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/d3766f449ca74b4caf509c031448a97f.gif]

Note that keyframes is executed as the picture grow.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? The code seems to work as expected for me. Can you please create a demo?

Comment: @Harry Version 49.0.2623.87 m

Comment: This is pretty ugly, but it shows the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/7mxutz3v/2/

Comment: Yes I can see the problem in the latest version of Chrome (but not in v43 -surprise!). I don't know why but the problem seems to be with `-webkit-filter` property. If you remove that and use only the standard, it works fine. Trouble is you can't remove `-webkit-filter` as older versions will still need it.

Comment: Doing it with 2 separates seems to do the job :
https://jsfiddle.net/q8n0q0d2/2/